# How can I make a second AJAX request inside the first AJAX's success method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have this ajax call. I'm requesting a json object that contains 2 strings. If the first one is not empty, I will display a confirmation popup to warn user and to get is decision whether  to proceed.

If the user decides to request the file, then the second string contains the **path** to the file.

So how can I make a second AJAX request inside the first AJAX's success method?

```
function reqQuote(_url)
{
   $.ajax({
      url: _url,
      success: function(data){
          if(data.itemsNotSupportedWarning != null){

         var r = Confirm('The template doesn\'t support the following languages: ' 
                         + data.itemsNotSupportedWarning + 
                         + ' Would you like to continue?');
            if(r == true)
            {
               //request the template file ...
            }
          }
          else{
             //there is no warning, i.e. just go ahead and request the template file.
         }
      }
  });
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You need to escape that apostrophe in `doesn't`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put another `$.ajax(...)` inside `if(r == true) { ... }` and define another success callback function for it.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the success method of the ajax call call some othe javascript methods where you can call ajax like normal ajax. See below.

```
    function reqQuote(_url)
    {
       $.ajax({
          url: _url,
          success: function(data){
                        testMethod();
      }
  });
}

function testMethod(){
    //Ajax Code Here
    }
```